# ng-repeat list in AngularJS isn't updated when an ajax call changing its value

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm totally confused. Why doesn't my ng-repeat refresh when there's an ajax call changing its value? I've seen many Q&As here, but none of them talked about ajax call.

HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="EntryCtrl">
    <div id="treeview" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="root in rootEntry">{{root.Name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function EntryCtrl ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.rootEntry = [];
    $http.get('read/root').success(function(root) {
        $scope.rootEntry = root;
        console.log($scope.rootEntry);
    });
}
```

And the console did log an array the server returned. But the list in html never got updated. If I used `$scope.$apply`, an error concerning `$digest` would happen.

**Console Output**

```
[Object]
    0: Object
        Attributes: null
        Id: "534580464aac494e24000001"
        Name: "Registry"
        Path: ""
        __proto__: Object
        length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

So it's the structure of `root` the server returns. Would it be the problem of data type? Because it's `Object` rather than `Array`. I use Golang as server and use `json.Marshal()` to pack the data from MongoDB.

**Update**

```
function EntryCtrl ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.rootEntry = [];
    $http.get('read/root').success(function(root) {
        $scope.rootEntry = root;
        console.log($scope.rootEntry);
    });
    console.log($scope.rootEntry);
}
```

The latter output is `[]`. It's likely because of async of $http, so will it the reason?

**Final**

I know why. I used a plugin called `jsTree`, which will do some decorations with the node, so the node I inserted would be overwritten.

Thank you all.

Comment: This should work fine, `$http` triggers a digest - are you sure the data is different when you get it back?

Comment: @tymeJV I'm sure it's different. More details have been updated in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code and as tymeJV said ,there is no problem with your implementation, i would suggest checking the console window for some possible errors.

Example:

```
function EntryCtrl ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.rootEntry = [];
    $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos').success(function(root) {
        $scope.rootEntry = root;
        console.log($scope.rootEntry);
    });
}
```

Live example : http://plnkr.co/edit/Grlgfob6tjE63JizWdCD?p=preview

Comment: Would you please have a look at the update of the question? I've put some details and thoughts about console output and data type.

Comment: it's an array that holds objects, [object,object...n] so I still don't understand why hasn't your view updated...