# NG-Repeat - Not Working In List (ninja image slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using a image slider called ninja slider, which currently works fine using the following html

```
<div id='ninja-slider'>
    <ul>
        <li><div data-image="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/402882947/1414953548/1500x500" href="http://www.menucool.com"></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However, when I am trying to get the data to come from a web service, it is not playing ball (not displaying any of the data) but I don't know where I am going wrong

```
 <div id='ninja-slider'>
          <div ng-controller="featCtrl">
            <ul>
                <li> <div ng-repeat="feat in featured" index="{{$index}}" data-image="{{feat.heder_img}}" href="http://www.menucool.com"></div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
```

With the following in my app.js file

```
.controller('featCtrl', function($scope, $http) 
{
    $http.get('http://liverpool.li/api/feat/home').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config)
    {
        $scope.featured = data.featured;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config)
    {});      
})
```

Am I doing it completely wrong? thanks

Comment: When you want data coming from an API call in a controller to appear instantly it's best using the resolve property on the route for that view/controller, see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider (resolve property) Your data will be ready before the view/controller is loaded

Comment: @BCLtd - Did you get it working? I am also trying the same and it is not working with ng-repeat? How did you get it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably the ninja slider.

Other people have this problem:

[ng-repeat list in AngularJS isn't updated when an ajax call changing its value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971468/ng-repeat-list-in-angularjs-isnt-updated-when-an-ajax-call-changing-its-value)

Try to init the plugin when your ajax call insert data into the $scope.

As I see in the plugin's site this can be hard.
Take a look at the docs of the plugin. If you have problem, use slickjs instead, however you have to use jquery for that plugin.

Comment: This will explain it i guess. I should go and read up a bit more. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in your code snippet is an error. In respect to the documentation you'd have to iterate over the `<li>`. You put the `ng-repeat` inside the `<div>` which will create multiple `<div>` elements. However, the [documentation](http://www.menucool.com/responsive-slider#view2) says that an image is wrapped inside a `<div>` which is then wrapped in a `<li>`. So change your code to the following:

```
<div ng-controller="featCtrl">
    <div id='ninja-slider'>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="feat in featured">
                <div index="{{ $index }}" data-image="{{ feat.heder_img }}"></div>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I am now iterating over the `<li>` element. Also you were referencing a scope variable `bar` but iterate over `featured`. However each item within the object is represented by `feat`. Thus you need to access the data from each element by using `feat`. Also I would think that you slightly need to change your controller because the JSON which gets returned by your `$http` call contains encoded URIs. You need to transform that by using the `decodeURI` function:

`https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/43128674\/1432932991\/1500x500` will become `https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/43128674/1432932991/1500x500`

You can use it by passing along the URL like so:

`decodeURI(url);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not doing anything with the ng-repeat. You are not using each of the `feat`. Maybe if you could do something like

```
<div id='ninja-slider'>
      <div ng-controller="featCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li> <div ng-repeat="feat in featured" index="{{$index}}" data-image="{{bar.heder_img}}" href="http://www.menucool.com">
                     <div>{{feat}}</div>
            </div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you try something like this?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, sorry it was a typo in the code I put on stack overflow. i have edited the post now, but it is still the same issue :(

Comment: If he use the ninja slider, it binds automatically all data-image in the page, changing the dom. So angular can't fetch the elements in ng-repeat

Comment: Try adding "feat in featured.data". You are forced to make this to let it work, also, you have to use something like {{feat.myField}}.

Comment: Any update on this? Did anyone get it working ng-repeat with ninja-slider?