# Displaying the contents of ng-controller after calling AJAX with the "as" function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

What I'm trying to show the contents of `ng-repeat` after calling AJAX (i.e. `$http`)

```
    <table ng-controller="TableController as tc">
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <!-- other headers are here -->
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="order in tc.orders" >
            <td ng-bind="order.id"></td> //It doesn't appear
            <td>@{{ order.id }}</td>     //It doesn't appear as well. I use Laravel, so I need to put @
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here is the relevant script part

```
angular.module('adminAngular', ['ui.bootstrap','dialogs.main'])
.controller('TableController', function(dialogs, $http){

    var instance = this;
    this.orders = [];
    $http({
        method : "POST",
        url : "/admin/getOrders"
    }).then(function (response) {
        this.orders = response.data;
        console.log("Inside; "+this.orders.length);
        });
});
```

From `console.log("Inside; "+this.orders.length)`, I can see that the expected data was assigned to `this.orders` array. However, as the title of this post suggests, the array is not displayed with `ng-repeat="order in tc.orders"`.

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971468/ng-repeat-list-in-angularjs-isnt-updated-when-an-ajax-call-changing-its-value), but following this did not solve this issue. Now I suspect that the cause lies in the `as` statement, which I have to use for this occasion.

As I don't see many information resources about the `as` online, I'd appreciate if you'd give any advice.

Comment: You could set a boolean flag and do something like `ng-show=retrievedData`

Comment: Use `instance.orders = response.data` in your `then()` handler. `this` in that context refers to the `function(response) {...}`, not your controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use your `instance`  inside promise resolved function 
to assign to the right instance (controller instance)  :

```
angular.module('adminAngular', ['ui.bootstrap','dialogs.main'])
.controller('TableController', function(dialogs, $http){
var instance = this;
instance.orders = [];
$http({
    method : "POST",
    url : "/admin/getOrders"
}).then(function (response) {
    instance.orders = response.data;
    console.log("Inside; "+ instance.orders.length);
        });
});
```

its usual to name this instance : `vm` refers to View Model

**Example:**

```
angular.module('adminAngular', ['ui.bootstrap','dialogs.main'])
.controller('TableController', function(dialogs, $http){
var vm= this;
vm.orders = [];
$http({
    method : "POST",
    url : "/admin/getOrders"
}).then(function (response) {
    vm.orders = response.data;
    console.log("Inside; "+vm.orders.length);
    });
});
```

Comment: What you name the variable is completely irrelevant

Comment: I didn't get it!  The controller instance could be called anything!  `instance` or `vm` . . . Updated the answer!